# not able to show array in Table @foreach

Tags: laravel

I am new to Laravel and coding. Trying to show Month name (Array) in table but not able to do the same. I tried few things like "json_encode" but got error each time.

My controller code is

```
 $months = array();
                    for ($i = 0; $i < 12; $i++) {
                        $timestamp = mktime(0, 0, 0, date('n') - $i, 1);
                        $months[date('n', $timestamp)] = date('M-Y', $timestamp);
                    }
```

Output is

```
     array:12 [▼
               3 => "Mar-2022"
               2 => "Feb-2022"
               1 => "Jan-2022"
               12 => "Dec-2021"
               11 => "Nov-2021"
               10 => "Oct-2021"
                9 => "Sep-2021"
                8 => "Aug-2021"
                7 => "Jul-2021"
                6 => "Jun-2021"
                5 => "May-2021"
                4 => "Apr-2021"
              ]
```

View file

```
    <table id="incometable" class="table m-0 table table-bordered table-hover table" data-order='[[ 0, "desc" ]]'>
                                        <thead>
                                          <tr>
                                            <th align="center">Month</th>
                                            <th>Milk Sale Amount (Rs.)</th>
                                            <th>Animal Sale Amount (Rs.)</th>
                                            <th>Other Sale Amount (Rs.)</th>
                                          </tr>
                                        </thead>
                                        <tbody>
                                          @foreach ($months as $item )
                                            <tr>     
                                              <td>{{ $item->$months  }}</td>
                                            </tr>
                                          @endforeach
                                        </tbody>
                                      </table>
```

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

During your `@foreach()` loop, `$item` is not an Object, it is a String `'Mar-2022'` through `'Apr-2021'`. You need to adjust your code:

```
@foreach($months as $key => $label)
  <tr>
    <td>{{ $label }}</td>
  <tr>
@endforeach
```

If you need the `1` through `12` values, they are available in each iteration as `$key`.

Comment: just one more point. If i need to add another <td> .... </td> Say total income amount , how can i add the same....

Comment: With your current code, that won't work; your array is `key => string`, like `1 => 'Jan-2022'`. You'd need to modify it to be `key => array` or `key => object`, like `1 => ['label' => 'Jan-2022', 'income' => 100]` then you'd be able to add an additional `<td>` element.

Comment: Attempt to add that yourself, and if you get stuck, please ask a new question 